# PS1='\\ $ ' and PS1='\\\\ $ ' are the same in bash

Tags: bash, shell, prompt

Both `PS1='\\ $ '` and `PS1='\\\\ $ '` produce visually the same prompt, `\ $`  in both cases.

Why? Is it a bug or documented behavior?

Tested on bash 5.2.021 and dash 0.5.12. I have only observed it in bash, but not in dash.

Comment: Just to add to your question, even `PS1='\ \$ '` returns the same prompt... So there are actually three cases where the prompt returns the same.

Comment: @aviro, `\$` is not the same as just `$`, the former tells the shell to display a `#` if you're root, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html

Comment: The same part of the manual mentions that `<backslash><backslash>` should produce a backslash, so indeed it seems odd that `<backslash><backslash><backslash><backslash>` still produces only one, and not two. (Noting that you used single quotes, so the issue is _not_ that one layer of backslash would be removed even before `PS1` gets assigned.)

Comment: @ilkkachu sorry, I didn't copy the correct command, I mean `PS1='\ $ '`.

Comment: @aviro, yep, `\ ` doing the same as `\\ `  makes sense in that backslash-space is an unsupported escape and gets copied as-is. Same as within double-quotes.

Answer (score 14):

Nice catch. This looks like a bug in [*decode_prompt_string*](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n5699) in parse.y.

From the PROMPTING section at `man bash`, it states that `\\` is considered a backslash. So `\\\\` should be considered as two backslash characters, but
at some point *decode_prompt_string* calls another function that merges backslashes, so those two backslash characters are merged into a single one. In short, every 4 consecutive backslashes in `PS1` will be merged to just one (of course, as long as the logic in the code remains the same).

If you actually want the prompt to print two consecutive backslashes, you'll need to add 2 or 4 more (`PS1='\\\\\\ $ '` or `PS1='\\\\\\\\ $ '`).

You can open a bug request by using the [`bashbug`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/BASHBUG/) tool (a utility for reporting bugs in Bash to the maintainers).

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug, just an (unnecessary?) example of consistency. The contents of the shell prompt undergo some amount of shell expansion before display (which is why you can do things like `PS1='$(git branch) \$'`. I think it's this expansion that further collapses a literal ``\\`` in the value of the prompt to a single backslash.

Comment: @chepner but the expansion/collapse should only happen **once**. In this case it happens twice. It's equivalent to if the command inside `PS1='$(command) \$'` produced a string in the form of `$(another command)` which will then be expanded again. So yeah, of course that ```\\``` should be collapsed to a single ```\```, but four of them should only be collapsed once to ```\\```.